# (Android) Native crash at /system/lib/libhoudini.so on Asus Phone

Tags: android, crash

I received crash errors very much from user at Google Play. 
And all those error occur on Asus phone ( Asus zenfone 4,5,6 and fonepad 7).

I don't known what those error is and how do i can fix those errors.

Hope someone can help me.

Log:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_ZenFone/ASUS_T00I:4.3/JSS15Q/WW_ZenFone-V4.1.0-20140428:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 6848, tid: 6958, name: fusoftware.ohtv >>> com.bfusoftware.ohtv <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr dead0000
eax 00000000 ebx 00000001 ecx 65441edc edx 00000000
esi 00000008 edi 0000b0b8
xcs 00000073 xds 0000007b xes 0000007b xfs 00000043 xss 0000007b
eip 651c3325 ebp 81cb6d0c esp 81cb6ce4 flags 00210246

backtrace:
#00 pc 00142325 /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#01 pc 00073704 /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#02 pc 00072599 /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#03 pc 0006ecb5 /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#04 pc 0006eeef /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#05 pc 0013bbc9 /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#06 pc 00139a1e /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.4.5.44375
#07 pc 000ffe5f [stack:6958]
```

Comment: Do you have any so file or use NDK within your project? If so what is your NDK version?

Comment: @jayatubi I don't us NDK. In my project, i used Vitamio library.

Comment: Is your `Vitamio` lib is `arm` only or it also provides an `x86` version? If so did you tried to use the `x86` version?

Comment: It's here: https://www.vitamio.org/
I don't know, but when i play video on Asus zenfone 4, it was crashes :-(

Comment: Oh I see. Did you fix your issue and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is anything you can avoid yourself. This is a direct crash from the device and the OS not your app.

I've had this as well, its not necessarily a problem with your app though. The phone could be doing lots of things in the background which causes something within the OS to crash, but your app somehow receives the crash report, not sure why, I would guess because your app was in the foreground when something within the OS crashed, your app received the crash info.

Comment: I am also getting this crash after I updated my app. I think there must be something wrong specifically somewhere that need to be fixed (the OS or 3rd part libs).

Comment: Take a closed look if all these crash reports are using Android 4.3 or earlier? I think Android have fixed this problem after 4.4: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77387

Answer (score 2):

libhoudini is responsible for running Arm code on x86 devices.
Sometimes it have bugs that are causing apps to crash.
The best solution is to include the x86 library too, that way the native code will run natively without using libhoudini, thus preventing any chance for such crashes.

Answer (score 0):

the android 6.0 system, I also met, looks like Google is not fundamentally solved this problem, the only way to solve is the X86 and arm library must be left apart.