# Having issues with a Frida gadget on an emulated Android device

Tags: android, arm, apk, emulation, frida

I am trying to inject a Frida gadget into an Android App which is already installed on an emulated (MEmu) Android 7.1 rooted system.

When I connect to the device using adb, I can see that the files are store here:

```
ASUS_Z01QD:/data/app/com.turtle.foo.bar-1 # ls
base.apk  lib  oat  split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk
```

The MEmu emulator uses an arm translator, if I browse into the lib folder:

```
ASUS_Z01QD:/data/app/com.turtle.foo.bar-1/lib/arm # ls
lib_burst_generated.so  libil2cpp.so  libfooservices.so  libxlua.so
libgpg.so               libmain.so    libunity.so
```

I can see a bunch of native lib's, so I downloaded the libmain.so and used Python's lief module to inject the gadget like so:

```
>>> import lief
>>> libnative = lief.parse("libmain.so")
>>> libnative.add_library("frida-gadget-14.0.8-android-arm.so")
<lief.ELF.DynamicEntryLibrary object at 0x7fcf140d0570>
>>> libnative.write("libmain.so")
>>> exit()
```

When running the file command on the original libmain.so and the frida-gadget-14.0.8-android-arm.so, I get confirmation that I am using the appropriate lib's in terms of CPU architecture:

```
libmain.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e7a78851143615daaa72ee2f6dd6b81641d0803d, stripped

frida-gadget-14.0.8-android-arm.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

The injection seems to work fine:

```
readelf -d new-libmain.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x8000 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x803c
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   368 (bytes)
 0x00000017 (JMPREL)                     0x2fd8
 0x00000014 (PLTREL)                     REL
 0x00000011 (REL)                        0x2f40
 0x00000012 (RELSZ)                      152 (bytes)
 0x00000013 (RELENT)                     8 (bytes)
 0x6ffffffa (RELCOUNT)                   13
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x21f0
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0x19000
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      4096 (bytes)
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x2c08
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [frida-gadget-14.0.8-android-arm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libmain.so]
 0x0000001a (FINI_ARRAY)                 0x7ec4
 0x0000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)               8 (bytes)
 0x00000019 (INIT_ARRAY)                 0x7eec
 0x0000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)               4 (bytes)
 0x6ffffff0 (VERSYM)                     0x2e4c
 0x6ffffffc (VERDEF)                     0x2ee4
 0x6ffffffd (VERDEFNUM)                  1
 0x6ffffffe (VERNEED)                    0x2f00
 0x6fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)                 2
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0
```

I then copied the new libmain.so and the frida-gadget-14.0.8-android-arm.so to the /data/app/com.turtle.foo.bar-1/lib/arm on my Android system. When I start the App it crashes. In logcat I see the following:

```
11-18 07:16:41.748  5759  5759 F Frida   : Unsupported Android linker; please file a bug
11-18 07:16:41.748  5759  5759 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5759 (aven.adventures)
11-18 07:16:41.748    80    80 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=5759 uid=10047 gid=10047 tid=5759
11-18 07:16:41.759  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-18 07:16:41.759  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Asus/Asus/ASUS_Z01QD:7.1.2/20171130.376229:user/release-keys'
11-18 07:16:41.759  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
11-18 07:16:41.759  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
11-18 07:16:41.759  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : pid: 5759, tid: 5759, name: flush-8:0  >>> com.turtle.foo.bar-1 <<<
11-18 07:16:41.759  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Unsupported Android linker; please file a bug'
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 0000167f  ecx 0000167f  edx 00000006
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     esi b778258c  edi b7782534
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     eip b76aea90  ebp bfdc9078  esp bfdc901c  flags 00000292
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000a90  [vdso:b76ae000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0007c04c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00077895  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+85)
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00027a0a  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+42)
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0001ef46  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+86)
11-18 07:16:41.760  5804  5804 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00222c1c  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
```

It seems to talk about an unsupported Android linker version and the crash appears to be related to libhoudini.so which is the arm translator which run's on MEmu. Any idea's how I can get arround this. The App which I am testing is only available for arm systems and I do not have a rooted physical arm Android device to test. I am trying to remove OKHTTP SSL pinning for the App using Frida.

Comment: There are siliar issues mentioned in the Frida issue tracker: https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/876 You may try on older Frida version (e.g. 12.4.x for gadget and python Frida package). If that does not help Frida gadget is not supported on your device.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into similar issue while the apk i was working on was (armeabi-v7a), i simply switched from Memu x86_64 (Android9 64bit) version to Memu x86 (A7 32bit), and now it somehow works!

you can go thru some replies in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240693/android-native-crash-at-system-lib-libhoudini-so-on-asus-phone)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).